# How to run multiple scripts and other after completion of previous scripts in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, parallel-processing

I have to run couple of scripts with arguments and after completion of those again i have to initiate another couple of scripts in Unix. Could you please advice me of the code sample and it would really helpful in design.

I had thought to do so:

```
function(parameter) {
   echo "script starting"
   nohup $parameter &
   sleep 1
   echo "script started"
}

function script_sample.sh $1 $2 $3
function script_sample.sh $2 $4
function script_sample.sh $1 $4 $5

wait (wait command to wait for above script to complete)

# after above, i have to initiate below scripts

function script_sample.sh $2 $3
function script_sample.sh $1 $2 $3
function script_sample.sh $2 $3 $4

wait

... (continuation of code)
```

any other idea would be appreciated and helpful??

Thanks

Comment: Technical comment: avoid naming your function as 'function'. Call it 'fork_job' or similar. Also, what is wrong with your approach ? what problem are you facing ?

Comment: Thanks, I just want to have some other technique for better code quality.

Comment: Re quality: the function definitions does not follow bash grammar. Also better to redirect each nohop job to different stout, otherwise the you will only have the log of the last job.